# State arrays (not objects) and the spread operator

Tags: reactjs

I am updating a sub array in a react state array of 'components' with a new key value like this.

```
this.setState({
    components: {
       ...this.state.components,
       [this.state.key]: {
          ...this.state.components[this.state.key],
          [key]: v
      }
    }
});
```

this works but it changes this.state.components from an array into an object which I don't want.

I can do

```
var result = Object.keys(this.state.components).map(function (k) {
   return { [k]: this.state.components[k] };
});

this.setState({components: result});
```

to fix the data but it seems messy and inefficient to set state twice. Is there a better way? I've tried various forms of using [] instead of {}, but from my understanding of the spread operator this should work.

Comment: Native javascript functions are not very good for the manipulation of immutables. I recommend to use a library, e.g. https://github.com/aearly/icepick to perform operations. You can even use the famous *Immutable.js* lib.

Comment: For example, using icepick library, this would be done as `this.setState(prevState => i.setIn(prevState, ['components', prevState.key, key], v))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` on the `components` array currently in state and return the object as is if the `key` in the state doesn't match the component index, or change the `[key]` property if they do match.

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  components: prevState.components.map((c, index) =>
    prevState.key === index ? { ...c, [key]: v } : c
  )
}));
```